# Почему не работает код на Java

Tags: java

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Width:");
    int width = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Height:");
    int height = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Name:");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    GUI frame = new GUI(name, width, height);
```

Программа спрашивает высоту, ввожу высоту, спрашивает длину, ввожу длину, спрашивает имя и сражу же создаёт объект класса GUI, не дожидаясь моего ответа

Comment: Почитайте дубликат... а также почитатйте подобные вопросы на стаке. они были уже.... проблема в nextInt

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` не читает следующий символ новой строки, поэтому первая `nextLine()` (которая [возвращает оставшуюся часть текущей строки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())) всегда будет возвращать пустую строку.

Попробуйте, например, изменить свой код так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Width:");
int width = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Height:");
int height = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Name:");
String name = "";
while (!(name = scanner.nextLine()).isEmpty()) { //проверка на пустую строку, когда еще ничего не введено
    GUI frame = new GUI(name, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Либо же, если это не важно, поставить name в начале.

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Name:");
      String name = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Width:");
      int width = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Height:");
      int height = scanner.nextInt();
 GUI frame = new GUI(name, width, height);
```

Comment: Точно, это даже проще! :)